# Rails app not working with Nginx + Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a rails application at

```
/home/myuser/webapps/myapplication/
```

I have installed and configured Passenger and Nginx but can't get my rails application to work properly. If I start the application with WEBrick it works just fine...

This is my nginx.conf file for this app...

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name www.mydomain.com.ar;
    root /home/myuser/webapps/myapplication/public;
    rails_env production;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

If put a static index.html within /home/myuser/webapps/myapplication/public/ it works OK. But since my application doesn't use this as root I guess Nginx can't load my app.

What am I missing? I've been reading a lot starting [here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app)

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, rvm 1.15.8, ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.8, Phusion Passenger 3.0.17, Passenger's Nginx module.

I have not used any deployment tool. I've just copied the root application folder to the location where the server is pointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the openssl support I was selecting when installing passenger-nginx-module was giving me a hard time.

I reinstalled and configured passenger & nginx in a fresh environment using `libcurl4` instead of `libgnutls` and my problem dissappeared.

Comment: Hi Alejandro , i am also stuck up with some broken packages , can you help me out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643845/phusion-passenger-nginx-installation-issue-on-debian-6-0-5-amd64-due-to-broken-p